# How do I assign an arbitrary value to a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unique-ptr

Is there a way to assign an *arbitrary* value to a `unique_ptr`?

Let's say I have some `unique_ptr` of an object. For testing purposes, I want to have this `unique_ptr` to be `!= nullptr`, and/or `pObj.get() != 0` without having to construct the object.

```
std::unique_ptr<someObj> pObj;
assert(!pObj);

// OK, but not what I want
// pObj = std::make_unique<someObj>();
// assert(pObj);

// Assign a "fake" object at an arbitrary memory location have have the assertion to be true.
pObj = 1;
assert(pObj);
```

Comment: You can do something like `pObj.reset((someObj*)1);` if you really want to break your code - but I have serious questions as to what the purpose of that is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that needs this kind of 'abuse' of unique_ptr?

Comment: This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your original problem you need to solve? Why do you think such an assignment would solve that original problem? Please ask about your original problem directly instead.

Comment: one reason to use `unique_ptr` is that if you don't do something "wrong" it always holds a valid pointer that points to an existing object (unless it compares equal to nullptr). Thats why what you want to do feels wrong. Maybe you have good reasons to do it, what are they?

Comment: Assigning a "fake" object will cause the `unique_ptr` to crash when it tries to invoke a destructor on invalid memory, unless you call `release()` on it beforehand.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has alias constructor to point to existing object, and uses control block of another `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: For all who are questioning why I would do such thing, I just need this for unit-tests I basically mock all calls where the object would be relevant but I have to somehow trick the nullptr check to take the branch. The solution of @UnholySheep at least compiles, but if I run the code I get an Seg fault, I assume when the "fake" obj is destructed. Any ideas to break my code even more or am I just on the wrong path here and I have to rethink my whole approach like some of you already suggested.

Comment: That really doesn't explain why you want to avoid creating objects for your tests in the first place. What exactly are you testing when you don't have proper objects? That `std::unique_ptr` works?

Comment: OK nevermind just saw the comment of @RemyLebeau release() did the trick for me.

Comment: Why can't you construct mocked `someObj` instead? Is it the design of `someObj` that doesn't have default constructor? In general it would be better to modify the production code to accept `std::unique_ptr` of some light interface that can be mocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize the answers given in the comments of the question.

The new code has to look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<someObj> pObj;
assert(!pObj);

// Assign a "fake" object at an arbitrary memory location
pObj.reset((someObj *)1);
assert(pObj);

// release before unique_ptr is destructed!
// Else we would get an Segmentation Fault
// when the "fake" objects destructor is called by the unique_ptr.
pObj.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine std::unqiue_ptr with std::optional for this:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::optional<int>> p;
assert(!p);
p = std::make_unique<std::optional<int>>(std::nullopt);
assert(p);
assert(!(*p));
```

Comment: This violates the OP's explicit requirement of "*without having to construct the object*". You are constructing the type of object that the `unique_ptr` is declared to hold a pointer to, regardless of the value you are assigning to that object.

Comment: Let OP say what they mean "without having to construct the object". Without constructing any object at all? Or without constructing someObj only?

Comment: it is pretty obvious that the OP doesn't want the `unique_ptr` to point at a valid object at all, and certainly not a constructed object.